# How can I get Bit Error Rate or Packet Error Rate for a bluetooth device from Android code?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

So there seems to be an API which allows me to get Bluetooth RSSI for a device:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#EXTRA_RSSI

And for GSM, there's an API to get bit error rate:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getGsmBitErrorRate()

What I can't find, is any way to get bit/packet error rate for Bluetooth... is there any way to get this information from the Android host?